# Не работает ввод текста pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, pyautogui

Ввожу правильный код. Всё работает, но программа текст не вводит.
Код:

```
import pyautogui as pg

pg.click(158, 0, duration=0.5)
pg.click(305, 58, duration=0.5)
pg.click(758, 717, duration=0.5)
pg.typewrite('This program works!', 0.5)
pg.typewrite(['enter'])
```

Comment: pyautogui.write тоже не работает ?

Answer (score 1):

Такая проблема возникает, если при запуске программы была выбрана русская раскладка, причем не решается она даже через замену ввода на вставку из буфера

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

или смену раскладки через winapi